# 5V power supply using 7805 with multiple outputs

Tags: power-supply, multisim

I need to make a 5V power supply using LM7805 IC but it should have multiple outputs I'll be needing 6 outputs for my project.
Can anyone guide me how do I build a circuit on multisim for the same?

Comment: As long as the sum of the current on each branch isn't higher than 500mA it's gonna be ok. Even if 7805 only have 1 output, you can connect 6 wires on it

Comment: if i connect 6 wires to it will it provide stable 5V supply to all the wires connected?

Comment: Yes, as long as you dont drag more than 500mA. Otherwise, the 7805 may heat up and may not provide 5v

Comment: Does the water tank in your house know how many taps you have connected to the plumbing?

Comment: The datasheet tells you the circuit you need to build. All it matters now is the current draw.

Comment: The practical current limit will likely be determined by thermal considerations (such as the presence or lack of presence of a heatsink, and if present how good it is). Somewhere between 1A and 20mA, most likely.

Comment: What Spehro said ... Also note that the power dissipated by the 7805 (and thus how hot it gets) will not only be affected by the current draw, but also by how high the input voltage is: P = (Vin-Vout)*I = (Vin-5)*I

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter how wire you connect to the 7805's output. The only things matter is how much current you will ask for. According to the datasheet, the 7805 can provide 500mA. This mean the sum of the current on each branch have to be lower than this value. Otherwise, the chip will heat up and may not behave as usual.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnXQuA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another condition: $$ V_{IN} \geqslant V_{OUT} + V_{DROPOUT}$$ If this condition isn't satisfy, the LM7805 won't guaranty 5V.

Comment: The last sentence is not strictly true. The supply voltage \$V_{IN}\$ is satisfied by the equation \$V_{IN} = V_{dropout} + V_{OUT}\$ where \$V_{dropout}\$ is specified in the datasheet. For example [this datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/41/4f/b3/b0/12/d4/47/88/CD00000444.pdf/files/CD00000444.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000444.pdf) shows it as 2V (typical)

Comment: I just edit my post in order to correct it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how many connections you connect to the output of the 7805, each connection will have 5V.

The important thing is how much current you draw from the 7805, depending on the combined current of all connections/branches you may need a heatsink with the regulator and the types of packages you can use may be limited.

The TO-220 package type can typically supply 1A to 1.5A (depending on which you buy) as long as you have the appropriate heat dissipation (heatsink)
The TO-92 package type can only supply around 100mA so make sure you pick the appropriate device.

In the datasheet of any regulator you will find a value called *Dropout Voltage*, this is the voltage that is dropped across the regulator. Therefore your supply voltage will need to be the same as \$V_{OUT} + V_{dropout}\$.